# Python lxml objectify: Strange behaviour when changing an elements value

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror, lxml.objectify

I´m new to stack overflow, so "hi" to everbody and I hope someone can help me with my question...

Recently I start to play around a bit with lxml.objectify and stumble over the following behavior, which I found to be strange.
If I just create a little xml string like this:

```
from lxml import objectify 

objroot = objectify.fromstring("<root>somerootvalue<child1/><child2/><child3/><child4><subchild1/><subchild2/></child4><child5><subchild1/><subchild2/></child5></root>")
objroot.child4 = True
objroot.child4.subchild1 = "Foo"
objroot.child4.subchild2 = "Bar"
print(objroot.child4.subchild1,objroot.child4.subchild2,objroot.child4)
```

The output is just: Foo Bar true

If I change the value/text of the elements then by:

```
from lxml import objectify 

objroot = objectify.fromstring("<root>somerootvalue<child1/><child2/><child3/><child4><subchild1/><subchild2/></child4><child5><subchild1/><subchild2/></child5></root>")
objroot.child4 = True
objroot.child4.subchild1 = "Foo"
objroot.child4.subchild2 = "Bar"
print(objroot.child4.subchild1,objroot.child4.subchild2,objroot.child4)
objroot.child4 = False
objroot.child4.subchild1 = "Foo"
objroot.child4.subchild2 = "Bar"
print(objroot.child4.subchild1,objroot.child4.subchild2,objroot.child4)
```

The output is as expected:
    Foo Bar true,
    Foo Baz false

But if I just change the value of objroot.child4 and call the print statement, I´ve got the following error:

```
from lxml import objectify 

objroot = objectify.fromstring("<root>somerootvalue<child1/><child2/><child3/><child4><subchild1/><subchild2/></child4><child5><subchild1/><subchild2/></child5></root>")
objroot.child4 = True
objroot.child4.subchild1 = "Foo"
objroot.child4.subchild2 = "Bar"
print(objroot.child4.subchild1,objroot.child4.subchild2,objroot.child4)
objroot.child4 = False
objroot.child4.subchild1 = "Foo"
objroot.child4.subchild2 = "Bar"
print(objroot.child4.subchild1,objroot.child4.subchild2,objroot.child4)
objroot.child4 = True
print(objroot.child4.subchild1,objroot.child4.subchild2,objroot.child4)
File "src\lxml\lxml.objectify.pyx", line 450, in lxml.objectify._lookupChildOrRaise (src\lxml\lxml.objectify.c:6586)
AttributeError: no such child: subchild1
```

While I expect the last output to be "Foo Bar true", I´ve got the "no such child error".
So it seems that the remaining part of the tree behind child4 has been cut of? Is tha a desired behavior and if yes how can I change the text of an element in the middle of the tree without cutting the rest of?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not that strange of behavior once we dig into it a bit.  Using `root.element.subelement....` is not performing as you might assume it is.  We can use `etree` to print out the state of the xml tree and check the structure.

```
from lxml import objectify, etree

objroot = objectify.fromstring("<root>somerootvalue<child1/><child2/><child3/><child4><subchild1/><subchild2/></child4><child5><subchild1/><subchild2/></child5></root>")

print(etree.tostring(objroot, pretty_print=True)

#output:
<root>somerootvalue
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <child3/>
    <child4><subchild1/><subchild2/></child4>
    <child5><subchild1/><subchild2/></child5>
</root>
```

This looks correct.  So what happens when we call `objroot.child4 = True`?  The API allows you to do this, but it does not just add the text.  Rather, it replaces everything that was under `child4` with the text.  So the subelements get dropped.  We can check using:

```
objroot.child4 = True
print(etree.tostring(objroot, pretty_print=True)

#output:
<root>somerootvalue
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <child3/>
    <child4 xmlns:py="..." py:pytype="bool">true</child4>
    <child5><subchild1/><subchild2/></child5>
</root>
```

So it has set the value of `child4` to `True`, but it has dropped the subelements.  After that, when you set the values of the subelements using:

```
objroot.child4.subchild1 = "Foo"
objroot.child4.subchild2 = "Bar"
```

It actually creates each subelement under `child4` and then sets the value on the fly.